# Htop signals seem not to be sent on (K)Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, htop, konsole

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 (Kubuntu), running through Konsole.

I have a node process I can see in htop if I F4 and search for node.  I highlight it and use F9 to send it a signal (tried SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL), but nothing causes it to exit.

This is not specific to node, as I can't SIGKILL other things (for example the Kate text editor).

If I exit htop and simply type `kill -SIGINT 6015` (PID taken from htop), the process exits properly.

Why is this not working?

I am guessing it has something to do with how the desktop version works, because on servers I have never had the issue of htop being unable to signal processes.

Another thing that goes contrary to my expectations is if I run `sudo htop` I can only see about 4 processes under my user (3 related to kde and one `(sd-pam)`) whereas running it as myself shows me 100+ (including node and all the other apps I have going).  I would expect that running as root I would see all processes for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good news, and bad news.

Kill works for `htop` installed with `sudo apt install htop`.

Kill **doesn't** works for `htop` installed with `sudo snap install htop`.

I believe snap's sandbox is blocking the signal.
Also, the htop from **snap** list fewer processes than the htop from **apt**.

Comment: Thank you, Marcos!  I was not aware of snap sandboxing applications installed through it.  Removing htop via snap and installing via apt solved my issue.  I am now able to send signals and see all the processes I expected to see.